# Check if the input value is valid in list using python

Tags: python

The programm is check if input value is valid in list.
below is my code. could you please help?thanks

```py
while True:  
    try:
        count = 0
        Day_list = []
        days =  int(input("Enter number : "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please input the integer")
    else:
        for i in range(days): 
            Day_list.append(float(input("Enter the day "+str(i+1)+ ": " )))
            if( 0<= Day_list[i] <=10):
   
                print('good' )
                                     
           else:
                print('Amount cant be negative, try again')
                break
```

i would like check the value one by one

eg.
**Enter the day 1 :** -1

then **output : Amount cant be negative, try again**

return **Enter the day 1 :** 1

**Enter the day 2 :**

but i dont have idea where is mistake,thanks

Comment: Maybe your indentation is wrong, should the `if( 0<= Day_list[i] <=10):` be nested under the for loop?

Comment: `Day_list[i] >= 0 and Day_list[i] <=10`

Comment: Hi, thanks all, I want to check every one, if the first day input value wrong, then output the message, but the program checks the all the value first , then show the wrong message.

Comment: applying the suggestion by rassar (if nested in the loop), it worked for me: it makes the check number by number. Maybe you can show which are the values you are inputting and the actual vs. expected output.

Comment: Hi @IgnatiusReilly, thanks for your reply and support. how to input until  a valid response. i modify my code and i try to input the wrong value, and then the program will  show next step, how to return to back until input the valid value.thanks

Comment: @iamnew maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) can help.

Answer (score 0):

here you are:

```
while True:  
    try:
        count = 0
        Day_list = []
        days =  int(input("Enter number : "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please input the integer")
    else:        
        if days >= 0:
            for i in range(days):             
                valid = False
                while not valid:
                    try:    
                        Day_list.append(float(input("Enter the day "+str(i+1)+ ": " )))
                        if( Day_list[i] >= 0 and Day_list[i] <=10):
                            print('good' )
                            valid = True
                        
                    except ValueError:
                        print ('input is not valid')
                break                   
                    
        else:
            print('Amount cant be negative, try again')
```

Comment: Hi Henro Sutrisno Tanjung, thanks for your reply and support, how to check the value when i input the wrong data , the program will show the error message and then i need to input again, if it is vaild value , the program will be show next step? thanks